# How to do random access or partial matching on a Flatbuffers binary object in Java?

Tags: flatbuffers

FlatBuffer supports random access. But I couldn't find any example/tutorial on how to do it in Java.

I looked into this article on how facebook uses FlatBuffer: https://code.facebook.com/posts/872547912839369/improving-facebook-s-performance-on-android-with-flatbuffers/
They are using some FlatBufferHelper class, which I couldn't find anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"random access" means that in FlatBuffers you can take a buffer of serialized data, and using the accessor functions, access any field of any object inside of it in any order.

To learn how to use it, you want to go here https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html and select "Java". The article you linked is about FlatBuffers at Facebook, and they may have their own (non-public) code.